# Does haproxy support OCSP for client certificate validation

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, haproxy, client-certificates, ocsp

We are configuring HAProxy to force require Client Certificate Validation. This works well. However, we couldn't find much information about OCSP support specifically for client certificate validation. There are information about Certificate Revocation list and OCSP Stapling (which I believe is for server certificates). 
So my questions are 
1. Does HAProxy supports OCSP during client certificate validation? 
and 
2. If it is supported, can this be manually configured without requiring the OCSP URL included in the client certificate itself or possibly overriding the url on the server?

Answer (score 1):

> We are configuring HAProxy to force require Client Certificate Validation.

Please define exactly what Client Certificate Validation means to you. You say it works well, so my best guess is that you're generating client certificates and you have configured haproxy to require valid client certificates in order to access resources that haproxy is in front of.

> However, we couldn't find much information about OCSP support specifically for client certificate validation. ... 1. Does HAProxy supports OCSP during client certificate validation?

No. That's quite simply "out of scope" for a server like haproxy. HAproxy only does OCSP stapling, and only then if you supply the OCSP response in the form of .ocsp files in the certificate directory. It's unusual to want haproxy to block TLS connections while it tries to get HTTP responses from each TLS certificate for all the reasons that OCSP stapling exists. Along those same lines, having haproxy block TLS connections from your clients while it tries to validate their certs via OCSP (or for that matter, CRLs) is not a good idea.

Update: See [this thread in the haproxy forums](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/ocsp-on-haproxy/716).